# How to add amount into UITextField on click of UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield, logical-operators

I have a`UITextField` and below that 3 button. User can enter the amount in`UITextField`. And When user clicked the button below`UITextField` it will add the amount in`UITextField` with amount written in button.

First button will add 100, Second will add 500 ad 3rd will add 1000. What is the best method to achieve it.

[image]

I try to implement following but got button.tag=0

```
/*Amount increment*/
- (IBAction)Btn_Incr100:(id)sender {
    [self addTextFieldValue:nil];
}

- (IBAction)Btn_Incr500:(id)sender {
    [self addTextFieldValue:nil];
}

- (IBAction)Btn_Incr1000:(id)sender {
    [self addTextFieldValue:nil];
}



-(void)tagNumber{

    Btn_Incr100.tag=1;
    Btn_Incr500.tag=2;
    Btn_Incr1000.tag=3;


}

-(void) addTextFieldValue:(UIButton*) button
{
    int amount=[Txt_Amount.text intValue];
    int AddAmount;
    NSLog(@"button.tag%d",button.tag);


    if (button.tag==1) {
        AddAmount=100;

    }
    else if (button.tag==2) {
        AddAmount=500;

    }
    else if(button.tag==3) {
        AddAmount=1000;

    }else{
        AddAmount=0;

    }

    amount=amount+AddAmount;

    Txt_Amount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",amount];

    NSLog(@"%d",amount);
    NSLog(@"%@",Txt_Amount.text);



}
```

Comment: please try my code it will solve your problem and it is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using it by implementing tag

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self tagNumber];
}


-(void)tagNumber{

    Btn_Incr100.tag=1;
    Btn_Incr500.tag=2;
    Btn_Incr1000.tag=3;


}

-(void) addTextFieldValue:(UIButton*) button
{
    int amount=[Txt_Amount.text intValue];
    int AddAmount;

    int buttonTagIndex = button.tag;
    switch (buttonTagIndex) {
        case 1:
            AddAmount=100;

            break;
        case 2:
            AddAmount=500;

            break;
        case 3:
            AddAmount=1000;
            break;
        default:
             AddAmount=0;
            break;
    }

    amount=amount+AddAmount;
    Txt_Amount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",amount];



}

- (IBAction)btnAmountClick:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    [self addTextFieldValue:button];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this you can achieve:

```
-(void)displayvalue:(id)sender {       
    UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@" The button's title is %@." resultButton.currentTitle);
}
```

and now you can set this text inside your textfield.

Comment: Second option: check with the help of tag, UIButton *button = sender;
int buttonTagIndex = button.tag;

Comment: I m trying to achieve using tag can you explain me how to do that

Comment: add three different tag to the buttons like 100,200,300. -(void)displayvalue:(id)sender {       
    UIButton *button = sender; int buttonTagIndex = button.tag; switch (buttonTagIndex) {
        case 100:
            populate text to textfield
            break;
            
        case 200:
            populate text to textfield
            break;
            case 300:
            populate text to textfield
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Add this method as every button action.

```
-(void) addTextFieldValue:(UIButton*) button
{
        NSString *string;

        if ([button.text hasPrefix:@"+"] && [button.text length] > 1)
        {
            string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
        }

        int textFieldValue =[textField.text integerValue] + string.integerValue;
        textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",textFieldValue];
}
```

Comment: can you explain me how to do that

Comment: I think using tag  is better since we can seperate each button but i am not able to achieve it

Comment: No need to use tag. Just set button title to be like @"+500", @"+1000". And add my method as action method for all button and it will take care of incrementing textfield. In future if you even change the amount, it will work without any problem because my approach is based on getting the incrementing value from button title. Using tag is cumbersome .

Comment: @user007007 you are write but i think using tag is easy.

Comment: If you use tag with button then you have write separate switch case for each incrementation. For example if you have 5 buttons like this then you have to deal with 5 switch cases with same piece of code logic. And using tag is less flexible.

Comment: No. need to write 5 switch cases

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *string;

    if ([button.text hasPrefix:@"+"] && [button.text length] > 1)
    {
        string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
    }

    int textFieldValue =[textField.text integerValue] + string.integerValue;
    textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",textFieldValue];
```

or
 connect separate actions

```
   -(IBAction) onClick1: (id) sender]
 { 
        NSLog(@"User clicked %@", sender);
        textField.text = [textField.text integerValue] + 100
 }
```

Comment: can you explain me how to do that

Comment: can you do same for question too

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do like this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   _txtAmount.text=@"0";

   _btn100.tag=100;
   _btn500.tag=500;
   _btn1000.tag=1000;


}

- (IBAction)btnAmountClick:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *btn=sender;

   if (btn.tag==100)
   {
     [self addAmount:@"100"];

   }
   if (btn.tag==500)
   {
     [self addAmount:@"500"];

   }
   if (btn.tag==1000)
   {
     [self addAmount:@"1000"];

   }

}


-(void)addAmount:(NSString*)strAmount
{
   int amount=[_txtAmount.text intValue]+[strAmount intValue];
   _txtAmount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",amount];

}
```

Comment: Same things is done multiple time So i want to do it once inside a function. int amount=[_txtAmount.text intValue];
   amount=amount+1000;
   _txtAmount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",amount];

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this way -

The three buttons below your textfield, link them all to a common method say,
-(IBAction)addBtnClicked:(UIButton *)btn

Given tags to three buttons like for button 100,
btn1.tag=100..
then for button 500, 
btn2.tag = 500..
then for button 1000, btn2.tag = 1000.

then in 
-(IBAction)addBtnClicked:(UIButton *)btn
{
int value = -1;
  if(btn.tag == 100)
{
  value =[txtFldText.text intValue] + 100;
}
else if(btn.tag == 500)
{
  value =[txtFldText.text intValue] + 500;
}
else if(btn.tag == 1000)
{
  value =[txtFldText.text intValue] + 1000;
}

txtFldText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];

}
```

Comment: you need to add button tag in inspection window.

Answer (score 0):

First set tag to every button like 0,1,2.

then connect IBOutlet of all button to single IBAction and 
 implement the IBAction as below.

```
 - (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
 {

   switch ([sender tag]) {

     case 0:
    {
        NSString *s=self.txtField.text;
        int add=[s intValue]+ 100;
        self.txtField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",add];

        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        NSString *s=self.txtField.text;
        int add=[s intValue]+ 200;
        self.txtField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",add];
    }
        break;

    case 2:
    {
        NSString *s=self.txtField.text;
        int add=[s intValue]+ 500;
        self.txtField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",add];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
  }

}
```

Comment: I will try to implement it and check it whether it will work or not

Comment: How will it detect which button is it

Comment: set tag to every button.

Comment: For 1st btn set tag  0. for 2nd btn set tag 1. for 3rd btn set tag 2.

Comment: @rijanmaskey i have checked (run ) it. you can also try it work perfectly.

Comment: Ok dude can you do same for the question too

Comment: i think some people have only for down voting and discouraging the people.

Comment: @rijanmaskey what happen on that day you have accepted my answer.. and now you are accepting author answer and down vote me.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better solution for this.
You can use tags smth differently, as they are.
Just tie your three buttons as actions to this method and set the tags to 100/500/1000

```
- (void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)(textfield.text.intValue + sender.tag)]; 
}
```